# SQL Join on Integer OrElse NULL

Tags: sql-server, join

I've got two tables that look similar to this.

```
Table 1
ID
Data
SomeData int NULLABLE

Table 2
ID
Data
OtherData int NULLABLE
```

I've got the following join at the moment.

```
Table1 Left Join Table2 On
      IsNull(Table1.SomeData, 0) = IsNull(Table2.OtherData, 0) AND
      Table1.Data = Table2.Data <-- I'll leave this out of the question below but it should be included in all queries.
```

That joins when `Table1.SomeData = Table2.OtherData`. This includes if they are both NULL.

How can I JOIN on `Table1.SomeData = Table2.OtherData`, but if there is no matching join, then instead JOIN on `Table2.OtherData = NULL`.

Comment: Why don't you just left join both, and coalesce?

Comment: Can you post some sample data along with expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ID1, Data1, SomeData, ID2, Data2, OtherData
FROM (
   SELECT t1.ID AS ID1, t1.Data AS Data1, t1.SomeData,
          t2.ID AS ID2, t2.Data AS Data2, t1.OtherData,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Data
                             ORDER BY CASE 
                                         WHEN IsNull(t1.SomeData, 0) 
                                              = 
                                              IsNull(t2.OtherData, 0) 
                                            THEN 0 
                                         ELSE 1
                                      END) AS rn
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 
      ON ((IsNull(t1.SomeData, 0) = IsNull(t2.OtherData, 0) 
           OR           
          t2.OtherData IS NULL) AND t1.Data = t2.Data) AS x
```

In case of both an equality between fields `Table1.SomeData`, `Table2OtherData` and `Table2.OtherData` being NULL, then the query will prioritize the record that satisfies the equality over the record that satisfies the second predicate.

Comment: should we wrap entire OR condition in '()'

Comment: If Table2 contains a match for both `Table1.SomeData = Table2.OtherData` and also `Table2.OtherData = NULL`, how can I return just the first one?

Comment: @KD Good catch. My query missed the starting parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from    Table1 Left Join Table2 On
          IsNull(Table1.SomeData, 0) = IsNull(Table2.OtherData, 0) AND
          Table1.Data = Table2.Data
    Union
select * from    Table1 Left Join Table2 On

          Table1.Data = Table2.Data
    where Table2.OtherData is NULL
```

EDIT: Didn't notice there wasn't a select statement in example

Comment: @cpburnz oh! I didn't notice the absence of select in example provided, see my edit. thanks